# Power BI Dax Group By Measure - Display Dates Before Today

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I am trying to create a measure that will show booked revenue over time, grouped by a few categories. I also want to show as 0 within line charts when the data is BLANK(), so I have it in an IF statement. Everything works just fine except for whatever reason I cannot get it to only show dates prior to today.

[image: LineChart]
Here is the current Measure:

```
M_BookedRevenue = 
VAR CurrentAccountingYear =
    CALCULATE ( MIN ( 'Date'[AccountingYear] ), 'Date'[Date] = TODAY () )
VAR CurrentDate =
    CALCULATE ( MIN ( 'Date'[SortDate] ), 'Date'[Date] = TODAY() )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
    IF (
        ISBLANK (
            SUMX (
                FILTER (
                    GROUPBY (
                        RevenueChannel,
                        RevenueChannel[ChannelBucket],
                        RevenueChannel[Channel],
                        'Date'[Date],
                        'Date'[SortDate],
                        'Date'[AccountingWeek],
                        'Date'[WeekNumber],
                        'Date'[AccountingMonthEnglishAbbrYear],
                        'Date'[AccountingMonth],
                        'Date'[AccountingYear],
                        "Revenue", SUMX ( CURRENTGROUP (), RevenueChannel[TransactionRevenue] )
                    ),
                    'Date'[AccountingYear] >= CurrentAccountingYear
                    && 'Date'[SortDate] < CurrentDate
                ),
                [Revenue]
            )
        ),
        0,
        SUMX (
            FILTER (
                GROUPBY (
                    RevenueChannel,
                    RevenueChannel[ChannelBucket],
                    RevenueChannel[Channel],
                    'Date'[Date],
                    'Date'[SortDate],
                    'Date'[AccountingWeek],
                    'Date'[WeekNumber],
                    'Date'[AccountingMonthEnglishAbbrYear],
                    'Date'[AccountingMonth],
                    'Date'[AccountingYear],
                    "Revenue", SUMX ( CURRENTGROUP (), RevenueChannel[TransactionRevenue] )
                ),
                'Date'[AccountingYear] >= CurrentAccountingYear
                && 'Date'[SortDate] < CurrentDate
            ),
            [Revenue]
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: What issue you are actually facing? Is it including data from today as well?

Comment: If you look at the chart it is including dates after today, it is just displaying 0 because there is no data. I want to hide those zeroes.

Comment: It seems you have Social data available till December 2020. Thats why the chart probably plotting the months till Dec, 20.

Comment: It is plotting the data until December because my measure is pulling the dates from my calendar dataset and I am wanting to show the zeroes, but only for dates prior to today. This is why I have the "&& 'Date'[SortDate] < CurrentDate" in the measure, but it doesn't seem to filter it out.

Comment: Yes @Femmer. pull up to today from calendar.

Comment: I do not understand.